# PowerShell Custom Columns Grid View

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm sure i've done something wrong, but i'm playing around with accessing multiple office 365 powershells and it works fine, but I want to add custom columns in my grid view. 1 column saying "Client Name" another saying something else. This is what I've got so far.

```
# Prompt For Login

[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')

$title = 'Email Address'
$msg   = 'Enter your email address:'

$emailAddress = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($msg, $title)

# Connect Office 365

if (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement) {
    Write-Host "Module Exists"
    } else {
    Write-Host "Module Does not Exist, Installing..."
    Install-Module ExchangeonlineManagement
}


$clients = @("ClientA",
             "ClientB",
             "ClientC",
             "ClientD",
             "ClientE")



$client = $clients | Out-GridView -Title "Choose a Client" -Passthru

# Make The Connection

Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName $emailAddress -ShowProgress $true -DelegatedOrganization $client
```

Comment: If you wish to select or add columns to your Grid View, use Select-Object cmdlet in a pipeline before the Out-GridView. I have provided a more detailed answer bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to send objects to `Out-GridView`.

This should help you get where you want:

```
$clients = [PSCustomObject] @{Client="ClientA";OtherData='Something'},
           [PSCustomObject]  @{Client="ClientB";OtherData='You'},
           [PSCustomObject] @{Client="ClientC";OtherData='Want'},
           [PSCustomObject] @{Client="ClientD";OtherData='To'},
           [PSCustomObject] @{Client="ClientE";OtherData='Show'}




$choice= $clients | Out-GridView -Title "Choose a Client" -Passthru

#the output from Out-Gridview is now an object, so use dot-notation to get the client.
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName $emailAddress -ShowProgress $true -DelegatedOrganization $choice.Client
```

Answer (score 0):

Your questions states: *"... I want to add custom columns... gridview"*

The answer:

This could be done by using **Select-Object** cmdlet in your query.
Putting it in a pipeline just before the Out-GridView commandlet allows you to add custom columns to the output.
Add custom columns of your choice by adding flag **-Property** and add columns to the output (in your case, it is the Out-GridView).

Here is an example script:

```
<# example for Custom Columns GridView with existing and custom columns #>

Get-Process | `
    Sort-Object CPU -Descending | `
    Select -First 10 | `
    
    <# Here is where you can select and create columns as you wish: #>
    Select-Object -Property `
        @{Label = "CPU(s)"; Expression = { if ($_.CPU) { $_.CPU.ToString("N") } } }, `
        <# added a Custom Column named "CPU(s)", calculated by using an Expression. #>

        @{Label = "MY Custom Column"; Expression = { ("MY " + $_.ProcessName) } }, `
        <# added a Custom Column named "MY Custom Column", calculated by using an Expression. #>

        ProcessName | `
        <# simply selected an existing Column named "ProcessName": #>

Out-GridView -Title "Top 10 CPU processes"
```

And here is the example of the resulting Out-GridView output:

[image: example Out-GridView output]

For more detailed explaination, you could see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-7.3#example-5-add-a-property-to-the-standard-get-process-output-display) from Microsoft which explains how to add properties to standard display and achieve what you need.